Django: Allowing a User being able to see, then update, form of their information
Im trying to create a game tracking app and I wanted the user to be able to see, then update if they wanted, a form that turns on and off features to track. I know this should be quite simple but I cannot for the life of me get the form to populate with the user's data, then be able to update it. Thanks in advance.
views.py
@login_required(login_url='my-login')
def track_pref(request):
    user = User.objects.get(username=request.user)
    print(user)

    if request.method == "POST":
        print('first if')
        form = UpdateTrackPrefForm(request.user, request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            print('Form Valid')
            obj = form.save(commit=False)
            obj.user = user
            obj.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/view-games')
    else:
        print("else statement")
        form = UpdateTrackPrefForm()

    context = {'form': form, 'user': user, }
    return render(request, 'gametracker_app/track-preference.html', context=context)

forms.py
class UpdateTrackPrefForm(forms.ModelForm):
    track_cedh = forms.BooleanField(required=False)
    track_wincon = forms.BooleanField(required=False)
    track_tournament = forms.BooleanField(required=False)
    track_medium = forms.BooleanField(required=False)

    class Meta:
        model = TrackPref
        fields = {'track_cedh',
                  'track_wincon',
                  'track_tournament',
                  'track_medium', }

models.py
class TrackPref(models.Model):
    track_cedh = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    track_wincon = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    track_tournament = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    track_medium = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    track_note = models.BooleanField(default=True)

    user = models.ForeignKey(User,
                             max_length=100,
                             on_delete=models.CASCADE,
                             null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.user)

html
<div class="container shadow-md p-5 form-layout">
    <h1 class="">Update Tracking</h1>
    <form action=""
          method="POST"
          autocomplete="off">
      {% csrf_token %}
      {{ user }}
      <br>
      {{ form.track_cedh|as_crispy_field }}
      {{ form.track_wincon|as_crispy_field }}
      {{ form.track_tournament|as_crispy_field }}
      {{ form.track_medium|as_crispy_field }}
      <br>
      <br>
      <input class="btn btn-primary"
             type="submit"
             name=""
             value="Submit">
      <br>
    </form>
  </div>

I've tried inserting the user into the view track_pref like below, but I get "argument of type 'User' is not iterable"
@login_required(login_url='my-login')
def track_pref(request):
    user = User.objects.get(username=request.user)
    print(user)

    if request.method == "POST":
        print('first if')
        form = UpdateTrackPrefForm(request.user, request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            print('Form Valid')
            obj = form.save(commit=False)
            obj.user = user
            obj.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/view-games')
    else:
        print("else statement")
        form = UpdateTrackPrefForm(request.user)


While Raphael got me very close, this ended up doing the trick. But, it was a great suggestion to change the model of 'TrackPref' to a OneToOneField.
views.py
@login_required(login_url='my-login')
def track_pref(request):
    track_pref = TrackPref.objects.get(user=request.user)
    form = UpdateTrackPrefForm(instance=track_pref)

    if request.method == "POST":
        form = UpdateTrackPrefForm(request.POST, instance=track_pref)
        if form.is_valid():
            obj = form.save(commit=False)
            obj.user = request.user
            obj.save()
            # I needed to go back to my previous code here

            return HttpResponseRedirect('/view-games')
    else:
        form = UpdateTrackPrefForm(instance=track_pref)
        # In this line, the call to get the user's preferences 
        # needed to be made to see their current preferences.

    context = {'form': form, }
    return render(request, 'gametracker_app/track-preference.html', context=context)



The way you are trying to include the user in the form, which does not expect two arguments (form = UpdateTrackPrefForm(request.user, request.POST)) as well as how you try to get the User might be the issue (user = User.objects.get(username=request.user).  request.user is a User, but username is NOT.  Try this:
# views.py

@login_required(login_url='my-login')
def track_pref(request):

    # The following are not needed, but the first is incorrect anyway
    # user = User.objects.get(username=request.user)
    # print(user)

    track_pref = TrackPref.objects.get(user=request.user)
    form = UpdateTrackPrefForm(instance=track_pref)

    if request.method == "POST":
        print('first if')
        form = UpdateTrackPrefForm(request.POST, instance=track_pref)    # NOTE THE CHANGE HERE
        if form.is_valid():
            print('Form Valid')
            form.save(commit=False)
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/view-games')
    else:
        print("else statement")
        # or, to troubleshoot,
        print((form.errors)
        # THIS IS NOT NEEDED
        # form = UpdateTrackPrefForm()

    context = {'form': form, 'user': user, }
    return render(request, 'gametracker_app/track-preference.html', context=context)

Setting the instance=track_pref should get the TrackPref that is being updated instead of creating a new instance.
Also, I'm not sure that a ForeignKey is what you would need, since I'm thinking each TrackPref is associated with only one User, and ForeignKey is a ManyToOne relationship.  Might be better to use a OneToOneField:
# models.py

class TrackPref(models.Model):
    track_cedh = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    track_wincon = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    track_tournament = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    track_medium = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    track_note = models.BooleanField(default=True)

    # NOTE THE CHANGE HERE
    user = models.OneToOneField(User,
                                max_length=100,
                                on_delete=models.CASCADE,
                                null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.user)

Edit
Actually, you don't even need the else statement, except to raise an error, or to message the user that there is an error, or to just print the errors for yourself to troubleshoot.  My error was not looking at the else statement at all, which is not needed, except as I just explained.

So, this didn't do what I was looking for just yet. Instead of displaying the current preferences, it outputs an empty form. Then, when you submit the form, instead of updating the preferences, it creates a new instance in the database.

I've update the answer, @bld-sync to perform an update to the form instead of creating a new instance in the database.  Hopefully this will work the way you intended.

I'm sorry this reply is so late. IRL issues. But this didn't help. Not only does it not show the user's current preferences, but it doesn't update the instance of the preferences when the form is submitted.

Yes, @bld-sync, you are correct.  I neglected to change the else statement, which is good to have as I explain in my edit and in the edited code, but not needed.  But I am happy you got it to work the way you wanted, and I am happy to have helped.
